# What is the meaning of 家 in this context?

Tags: meaning

As far as I understand the scentence below it means that it is necessary to take a break after 15 miutes of using a smartphone and other similar devices.

But with what purpose is 家 used there?

スマートフォンなどを１５分使ったあとは休むと**家**で決めることが必要です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of "家で" here is as simple as "at home".
It might also have the nuance of "in a family".

It seems that the sentence is on the context of discipline of children.
Here "決める" is "make it a rule" rather than simply "decide".
So "家で決める" is "make it a rule at home"; that is, "make it a rule as a part of home discipline".

So the whole sentence is advising us to teach children to take a break after 15 minutes of using a smartphone.